# Задание на файлы на си

Tags: c, файлы

Считывает только одну запись и потом перезаписывает новой. Все введенные записи должны идти по порядку. Помогите найти в чем ошибка.

```
  struct person
 {
    char  name[30];
    float money;
 };

   void add (char*);
   void show (char*);

   int main()
  {
     char file[50];
     char menu;
     puts ("Имя файла:");
     gets(file);
     do
    {
       system ("CLS");
       puts ("1.Добавление записи");
       puts ("2.Просмотр записи");
       menu=getchar();
       switch(menu)
       {
          case '1':add (file); break;
          case '2':show (file); break;
        }
    }
    while (menu!='3');
    return 0;
    }

    struct person input_client(void)
    {
       struct person client;
       getchar();
       puts("фио");
       gets(client.name);
       puts("сумма");
       scanf("%f",&client.money);
       return client;
    };

     void add(char*file)
    {
        FILE *f;
        struct person client;
        system ("CLS");
        if ((f=fopen("D:\\text.dat","a+b"))==NULL)
        {
             perror("Ошибка открытия файла");
             system("pause");
             return;
        }
      client=input_client();
      fwrite(&client,sizeof(client),1,f);
      fclose(f);
     }

      void show(char*file)
     {
        FILE *f;
        struct person client;
        int k=0;
        system("CLS");
        if((f=fopen("D:\\text.dat","r+b"))==NULL)
        {
            perror("Ошибка открытия файла");
            system("pause");
            return;
         }

         puts("|  N |  фио      | сумма |");
         puts("--------------------------");
         while(fread(&client,sizeof(client),1,f)==1);
         printf("|%3d |%-20s|%10.2f|\n", ++k,client.name,client.money);
         puts("--------------------------");
         fclose(f);
         system("pause");
        }
```

Comment: Уточните заголовок вопроса, пожалуйста. В чём состоит задание?

Answer (score 2):

Классика жанра -

```
while(fread(&client,sizeof(client),1,f)==1);
```

лишняя точка с запятой в конце... Просто уберите ее :)

Только - ну забудьте о существовании `gets`! Ну нет ее. всё...

И еще - если уж вводите имя файла от пользователя - то почему его не используете?

Answer (score 1):

У вас стоит точка запятой после этого while предложения

```
while(fread(&client,sizeof(client),1,f)==1);
                                          ^^^
```

Я думаю, вы имели в виду

```
 while(fread(&client,sizeof(client),1,f)==1)
 {
     printf("|%3d |%-20s|%10.2f|\n", ++k,client.name,client.money);
     puts("--------------------------");
 }
```

или

```
 while(fread(&client,sizeof(client),1,f)==1)
 {
     printf("|%3d |%-20s|%10.2f|\n", ++k,client.name,client.money);
 }
 puts("--------------------------");
```

Имейте в виду, что согласно стандарту C функция `main` без параметров должна быть объявлена как

```
int main( void )
```

Функции

```
   void add (char*);
   void show (char*);
```

следует объявить по крайней мере как

```
   void add (const char *);
   void show (const char *);
```

так как строка, передаваемая в эти функции в качестве аргумента, не изменяется.

Также имейте в виду, что функция `gets` не поддерживается стандартом С. Используйте вместо нее, например, стандартную функцию `fgets`.

Обращайте внимание на предупреждения компиляторы такие. как, например, неиспользуемые параметры или другие переменные.